# How to write this b in matrix form in matlab?

Tags: matrices, matlab

[image]

Can anyone help me write this b in matrix form in matlab?

I am letting n=10 for the dimension of A.

Comment: Can you make this a bit clearer? is the first entry just $(1+\frac{1^2}{(n+1)^4})$?

Comment: Sorry, I am not exactly sure, and this is the screen shot of the problem I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a vector? What is A? Is n a constant?

Can you write down what is the value of $b_{i,j}$?

Assuming b is a vector with n elements such that for $i\ne 1$ or $n$ then $b_i = \frac{i^2}{(n+1)^4}$

then in matlab you can write

```
n = 10;
i = 2:(n-1);
bmid = i.^2 / ((n+1).^4);
b = [1+1/(n+1)^4, bmid, 6+(n^2)/(n+1)^4];
```

Comment: I have posted a detail version of this problem that I need help with. You can see it in here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764835/gauss-seidel-iteration-in-matlab

Comment: While I do not know the Gauss Seidel iteration method, from what I can see it looks like the b I wrote down is in fact the transpose of the b you need. Also, my b and Davis Yoshida's are the same (although mine is a little more compact/efficient).

Comment: So, I have to take a transpose to get the b I need?

Comment: Yes. I think the b you need is

`n = 10;
i = 2:(n-1);
bmid = i.^2 / ((n+1).^4);
b = [1+1/(n+1)^4, bmid, 6+(n^2)/(n+1)^4]';` Note the transpose at the end of concatenation.

Comment: Yep it works. Now I wish if I could figure out the Gauss Seidel method :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's some clever MATLAB syntax that would make this more compact, but you could always do a for loop

```
n = 10;
b = [1 + 1/(n+1)^4]
for i = 2:n-1
    b = [b;i^2/(n+1)^4];
end
b = [b;6 + n^2/(n+1)^4];
```